# Menu bar - links of different widths to fill the fluid width of menu bar

Tags: html, css

I have a nav / menu bar with a max-width of 900px. Inside the nav bar is five links:

```
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="workshops.html">Workshops</a></li>
                <li><a href="production-workshop.html">Production workshop</a></li>
                <li><a href="about-us.html">About us</a></li>
                <li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact-us.html">Contact us</a></li>
            </ul>   
        </nav>
```

I would normally make the five links 20% width, to fill the width of the nav bar and be fluid.

However, because the link text has very different lengths "Production workshops" compared to "News", I want the widths of the links/tabs to be based on the text. I've added left and right padding to the links. But now this is not fluid (it breaks below 900px width) and I can't accurately get the links to fill the width of the nav bar.

Is there a way for the links to fill the width of the nav bar, have a flexible width and for the widths of the links/tabs to be different (based on the width of the text)?

A link to JS Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/j0g53wnu/

```
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="workshops.html">Workshops</a></li>
                <li><a href="production-workshop.html">Production workshop</a></li>
                <li><a href="about-us.html">About us</a></li>
                <li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact-us.html">Contact us</a></li>
            </ul>   
        </nav>




nav {
    background-color:brown;
  max-width:900px;
    }
nav ul {
    font-size:21px;
    line-height:60px;
    overflow:auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }

nav ul li {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }

nav a:link { color:rgb(255,255,230); background-color:rgb(0,0,0); border-right:1px solid rgb(255,255,230); display:block; padding:0 38px; }
nav a:visited { color:rgb(255,255,230); background-color:rgb(0,0,0); border-right:1px solid rgb(255,255,230); display:block; padding:0 38px; }
nav a:hover { color:rgb(51,153,51); background-color:rgb(0,0,0); border-right:1px solid rgb(255,255,230); display:block; padding:0 38px; }
nav a:active { color:rgb(51,153,51); background-color:rgb(0,0,0); border-right:1px solid rgb(255,255,230); display:block; padding:0 38px; }
```

Comment: flexbox can do that but it will depend on what this is **supposed** to look like.

Comment: Nav bar to be max-width 900px. The links inside the nav bar to be 100% width of the nav bar. For the links to have different widths, depending on the width of the text inside the links.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tgkn9bsw/1/

Comment: Thank you, but as mentioned in the opening post the widths of the links should not be the same. Otherwise Production Workshop only just fits, while 'News' has got loads of space.

Comment: So this - https://jsfiddle.net/m1v4wbex/

Comment: Or this using `display:table` - https://jsfiddle.net/7nmz6atq/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered flexbox?

Just changed a little, including flex-grow (to allow for the different sizes of the items.)

```css
nav ul {
 font-size:21px;
 line-height:60px;
 overflow:auto;
 text-align: center;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
  display:flex;
  box-sizing:border-box;
 }

nav ul li {
  flex-grow:2;
 text-align: center;
 list-style: none;
 }
```

Comment: Why `flex-grow:2` when `flex-grow:1` would do the same thing.

Comment: @Paulie_D  in your JSFiddle above when flex-grow is set to 1 all the links have the same width. Which isn't what I want. But when flex-grow is set to 2 it appears to work (the width of the links is relative to the text within the link)

Comment: No...my fiddlle had `flex:1` which is NOT the same as `flex-grow:1`. If all the links are set to the same flex-grow value then that seems to be what you are after. `flex-grow:2` is pointless and misleading - https://jsfiddle.net/rbyxndf0/

Comment: @ Paulie_D I don't know anything about Flexbox but flex-grow:2 just seems to work. See https://jsfiddle.net/cLzd1wqj/

Comment: @Jared flex-grow:1 acheives the same thing and is a nicer solution. Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it fuild with CSS Grid in many different ways, one quick easy approach would be like this:

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: ". . . . .";
 }

li {
  background-color: grey;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Here you can check a working version based on your same example:
https://jsfiddle.net/j0g53wnu/4/

Change the result area to see how it fixes the width.

Hope this help :)

Answer (score 0):

1) add this code to Cascade style sheet file

```
.display-flex {
  display:flex;
}

.fill {
  fill:1 1 auto!important
}
```

2) add class display-flex to UL tag

```
<ul class="display-flex"></ul>
```

3) add class fill to each Li tag

```
<li class="fill"></li>
```

If you need another solve,
You can come with me via email